# Как понять, насколько сильная ддос атака на сайт и какой тариф cloudflare подойдет?

Tags: ddos, cloudflare

Как понять, насколько сильная ддос атака на сайт и какой тариф cloudflare подойдет? Хватит ли бесплатного тарифа?
А также какие настройки выставить в cloudflare. Сейчас подключила cloudflare к сайту, но не понятно, прекратятся ли от этого сбои или спустя время снова возобновятся

Comment: А как вы поняли, что идёт ддос атака?

Comment: сайт перестал работать, написали в тп хостинга, там сказали